# Wordpress MU - Being able to access index .html and .php

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have an index `.html` hold page but I would like to access wordpress's `.php`.  What do I need to place into my .htaccess to enable this?

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%2/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed  a plugin called **Permalink Fix & Disable Canonical Redirects Pack** you can find it [here](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/permalink-fix-disable-canonical-redirects-pack/)